# Advanced Custom Fields - display label and value only if value entered

Tags: php, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, array, conditional-content

i currently have the following:

```
<?php

$field_name = "text_field";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);   

<table>
    <tbody>
    if( isset($field['value'] ): ?> 
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $field['label']; ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $field['value']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

my goal is to make the entire table row collapse and not display if there is no value entered.

clearly a novice. thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I was going to answer then I saw you edited it. Doesn't this new version work? It looks fine.

Comment: gives an error. perhaps syntax? d the echoes in the if statement need to be wrapped or something?

Comment: Oh, silly me, I'm blind... you need <?php before the if statement :P

Comment: ^^  what VesterDe said!

Answer (score 2):

You have a mismatch in your PHP tags.  Use this:

```
<?php
$field_name = "text_field";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);   
?>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    if( isset($field['value'] ): ?> 
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $field['label']; ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $field['value']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per ACF documentation, field[‘value’] will always be set.

Instead do if (!empty($field['value']) or just if ($field['value']).

Thus it should look like this:

```
<?php
$field_name = "text_field";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);   
?>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    if ($field['value']): ?> 
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $field['label']; ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $field['value']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```